# Selenium send keys sends text twice even after clearing

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, sendkeys

I'm trying to login to an application and hence trying to send username and password. Steps that I'm following

1. I'm identifying the field/waiting for the element to be clickable
2. clear any existing value in the field
3. send_keys(text)
4. wait for 1 sec to redo the operation for next field

Actual result -

1. Field is identified
2. Username is entered fully (let's assume it is 'abc@gmail.com'
3. Within a fraction of second, value is cleared and only first char of the text is re-entered ('a') and moves to next field password. This happens only for username field.

My code -

```py
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
    element = self.driver.find_element(*locator)

except NoSuchElementException:
    log.error("Element not found {0}".format(locator))
    pytest.fail(
        "Unable to find element. Please check locator {0}".format(locator))

except Exception as error:
    log.error("Unknown exception error {0}".format(error))
    raise

if text is None or text == "":
    log.error(
        "Type function cannot accept NULL value to enter for element {0}".format(
            locator))
    raise TypeError(
        "Type function cannot accept NULL value to enter for element {0}".format(
            locator))
else:
    element.clear()
    element.send_keys(text)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Have you debugged the issue?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML of the _username field_

Comment: HTML code - <input placeholder="Email or Phone" type="text" name="mobile" class="tiktokads-common-account-form-mobile" id="TikTok_Ads_SSO_Login_Mobile_Input" xpath="1">

Comment: locator in the code refers to  this --> Username = (By.ID, 'TikTok_Ads_SSO_Login_Mobile_Input')